# Object reference not set to an instance of object when using a List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, generics, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code snippet that produces a compilation error:

```
public List<string> batchaddresses;

public MapFiles(string [] addresses)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.Count(); i++)
    {
        batchaddresses.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(addresses[i], "*.esy"));
    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to use the `List<T>.AddRange()` method:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" ocurrs when you try to execute your code. It is not a compilation error, its a runtime error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where is batchaddresses initialized?

Declaring the variable does not suffice. You must initialize it, like so:

```
// In your constructor
batchaddresses = new List<string>();

// Directly at declaration:
public List<string> batchaddresses = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize the list

`List<String> batchaddresses = new List<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

The `batchaddresses` field hasn't been initialised. You can initialise it as part of the declaration:

```
public List<string> batchaddresses = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet, it doesn't look as though `batchaddresses` is initialised. Replace the line with this:

```
public List<string> batchaddresses = new List<string>();
```