# Unity3D Flight Simulator Chase Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a flight simulator and trying to make a chase cam with it. When I run the c# code it gives me this error --> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Plane.Pilot.Update () (at Assets/PlanePilot.cs:14) and the 14th line of code is Camera.main.transform.position = moveCamTo; how do I get rid of the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206810/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140047/how-to-solve-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031336/what-is-the-meaning-of-nullreferenceexception) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735570/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) ...

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413769/object-reference-not-set-to-an-object-calling-razor-model-from-view) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932823/nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557083/c-sharp-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408075/nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-object-reference-not-set-to) ...

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466878/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-object-when-using-a-listt-in-c-shar) or (approximtely 50 more) - when you are asked to check whether your question has been answered before, **please do so**.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are assigning null to *Camera.main.transform.position* (it's trying to reference an object, but it can only reference to null, causing the exception).

You need to assign a value to the *moveCamTo* variable before assigning it to *Camera.main.transform.position*.

You can also test to make sure the variable isn't null before assigning it:

```
if (moveCamTo != null) {
//moveCamTo is not null - you can assign it

}
```